Adjacent items in Quicksort's output: Does the algorithm guarantee they have been directly compared?
Is the direct comparison of adjacent items in the output array guaranteed by the Quicksort algorithm ?
In other words:
During the course of the sorting, the Quicksort algorithm makes (k-2)2^k+2 comparisons in the best case scenario and 2^(2k-1)-3*2^(k-1)+1 comparisons in the worst case scenario, when the number of elements to be sorted (N) is expressed as N=2^k-1.
That is a lot of comparisons, but can we be sure that the adjacent elements appearing in the sorted order in the output array "a[ ]", were directly compared at least once, during the course of the algorithm ?  Like this:
cmp(a[1], a[2]); cmp(a[2], a[3]); cmp(a[3], a[4]); ... ; cmp(a[N-1], a[N]);


@derpirscher:  In your opinion, which sorting algorithm makes such guarantee ?

Insertion sort or bubble sort for instance

I have an inkling some statements about this are going to rely on/imply unique key values.

Related to what I think you're doing: Which sorting algorithm uses the fewest comparisons?

Yes! Consider the tree formed by the various partition operations, with the pivot element for a partition associated with that node. Nodes are increasing in an in-order traversal. For any given non-maximum node, the node immediately after it in the sorted order is either an ancestor (indicating that, when that node was a pivot, this node was compared with it) or a descendant (indicating the converse).
I'm not sure how you'd use this guarantee, but it is there.
More generally, any comparison-based sorting algorithm has this property. Consider two nodes which end up consecutive in the sorted order. At some point they must have been directly compared with each other, because no transitive chain of comparisons could otherwise prove that the left one was less than the right one.
For instance, suppose the sorted order contained the pieces...foo, bar, baz, qux.... It's possible that foo and qux were never compared with each other: they could instead have each been compared with bar or baz, or one each could have been compared with each one and then bar and baz compared with each other. But you know that foo and bar were directly compared, because no other process could have established that the order should have been that one instead of ...bar, foo, baz, qux.... After all, there's no other element to help out.

Yue are right. But there is an edge case where comparisons are transitive, when several items are equal. Not sure what happens then ...

@vals In a three-way sort, you would instead say that all adjacent equivalence classes have been directly compared at least once. I could see how one could implement a three-way quicksort to only have this weaker property, but the "normal" way of doing it would likewise yield the stronger property.

@Sneftel:  I'm still analyzing your answer.  Also, regarding your question:  I'd use this guarantee to avoid repeating the same comparisons after the array is sorted.  In the Standard Library of the C language, the implementation of the qsort() uses a user-definable comparison function.  I would like to do additional work inside this function and take advantage of the comparisons that had already been made, so I do not have to repeat them after the Quicksort algorithm runs its course.  These comparisons are very expensive in my case as they involve 65536 bytes on average for each comparison!

@GeorgeRobinson Sounds fine, but keep in mind that even if you didn't have this guarantee, you could still use memoization to avoid recomputing the needed consecutive comparisons.
